# How to do this matrix"operation" in R?

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra

So I have this diagonal matrix

```
> M
   a  b  c  d
 a 2  3  5  4
 b .  3  6  4
 c .  .  4  6
 d .  .  .  3
 >
```

and what I want to do is the following, I want to access the the following elements:
**(a,a), (a,b), (a,c), (a,d)**. That would be easy, it would be just the first row.

But I would also be needing

**(b,a), (b,b), (b,c), (b,d)**. would be **(3,3,6,4)**

**(c,a), (c,b), (c,c), (c,d)**.  would be **(5,6,4,6)**

**(d,a), (d,b), (d,c), (d,d)**.  would be **(4,4,6,3)**

How could I access those? I would like to return a row or column vector in each case with these elements.
What I tried here was to copy those elements manually, but I really would like to how to do it in case of a larger matrix?

Comment: Does `apply( matrix, 1, function(x) x )` do what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want row vectors

```
asplit(M,1)
```

or column vectors

```
asplit(M,2)
```

where the vectors are stored in a list.

---

**Update**

```
M[lower.tri(M)] <- t(M)[lower.tri(M)]
res <- asplit(M,1)
```

such that

```
> res
[[1]]
[1] 2 3 5 4

[[2]]
[1] 3 3 6 4

[[3]]
[1] 5 6 4 6

[[4]]
[1] 4 4 6 3
```

---

**Data**

```
> dput(M)
structure(c(2, NA, NA, NA, 3, 3, NA, NA, 5, 6, 4, NA, 4, 4, 6, 
3), .Dim = c(4L, 4L))
```

Comment: thank you that was useful! but  unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem. I think I was not very clear in my OP. I edited it now, and described better what I exactly want